# How does malachite react with acid?

Tags: hydrogen

I performed an experiment where I did this:

> Add one spatula of malachite to a test tube, add dilute hydrochloric acid to the malachite until the test tube is one third full. Note observations and identify gas produced.

The green solid turned to a blue solution and there was an effervescence of hydrogen. However, I now realise that copper doesn't react with acid and malachite is a copper carbonate hydroxide mineral... 
I researched online and found that

> It dissolves in sulfuric acid to give Copper sulfate, Carbon dioxide
>   and Water.
>   http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_happens_when_malachite_is_dissolved_in_sulphuric_acid?classic=true

So how did I get that malachite reacted with acid and did produce hydrogen with a squeaky pop test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: P.S: Please could you include the formula to explain? Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, pure malachite $\ce{Cu2CO3(OH)2}$ usually doesn't produce hydrogen because it is a copper carbonate. Copper is already in a higher oxidation state (+2) so it can't reduce hydronium to hydrogen. The right reaction is the following:
$$\ce{Cu2CO3(OH)2 +2H2SO4 -> 2CuSO4 + CO2 ^ + 3H2O}$$

However, if there are traces of metallic copper some hydrogen can be produced but not with sulfuric acid because:

$$\ce{Cu + 2H2SO4 -> CuSO4 + 2H2O + SO2 }$$

Nor with $HCl$ (copper doesn't react with $HCl$)  but only with nitric acid or aqua regia you can produce hydrogen from the metallic form. So, in fact, the gas you see is carbon dioxide.

Comment: @TimTimmy the up arrow $\ce{ ^ }$ indicates that the compound become a gas and can escape from the solution the down arrow $\ce{ v }$ indicates that the compound precipitate. Have a look [at the bottom here](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf#page=8) for latex reference and [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_symbols_are_used_for_chemical_equations?#slide=12) for a general introduction to the symbols used in chemistry.

Comment: Just one last issue - in your last equation, copper reacts with sulphuric acid - why? I know that it is lower than hydrogen in the reactivity series, so how? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @TimTimmy yes in fact if you use sulphuric acid you normally add some hydrogen peroxide as oxidant agent however hot concentrate sulphuric acid is a good oxidant agent so it can dissolve copper. However is not very effective (see [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=y5mZrW1KB_AC&pg=PA90&dq=%22preparation+of+sulfur+dioxide+gas+from+sulfuric+acid+and+copper%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=A9QcU4W8BsnTsgbYoIGgDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22preparation%20of%20sulfur%20dioxide%20gas%20from%20sulfuric%20acid%20and%20copper%22&f=false) for reference).

Comment: Last thing hydrogen is not involved in this reaction so  the effective oxidant agent in concentrate sulphuric acid I think is $SO_4^{-}$ that is reduce to $SO_2$, this is the point.

Comment: @TimTimmy I've found [this](http://nsb.wikidot.com/c-9-5-3-6-1) and [this](http://nsb.wikidot.com/c-9-5-3-6-1) take a look maybe you could find them helpful. You are welcome!Thank you!